# understanding the fundamentals of quantile() and quantiles

Tags: r, statistics

If there are, say 59 observations, I'm confused why `quantile(data, probs = 0.05)` would put 3 values under the 5th percentile, as 3/59 = ~0.051.

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- seq(c(1:59))
b <-rnorm(59)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df_5thperc <- df %>% summarize(`05%` = quantile(b, 
probs=0.05))
y <- mean(df_5thperc$`05%`)
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept = y, color = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Quantiles AFAIK just means dividing up your observations into 5 evenly distributed buckets.  Note that if you data set is not evenly divisible by 5, then the buckets won't be even.

Comment: read `?quantile` for excruciating details about how the quantiles are defined/computed ...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - wouldn't that be a qu**i**ntile rather than a qu**a**ntile?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking. If R put the quantile between the 2d and 3d observation, then P(x<Q)=0.0339, obviously too small. If Q is between the 4th and 5th observation then P(x<Q)=0.0678, obviously too big.  Putting Q between the 3d and 4th observation and getting P(x<Q)=0.0508 is the best that can be achieved (the 0.05 quantile will never have P(x<Q)==0.05 unless  N is divisible by 20).

Comment: @thelatemail You have released the cat which bit my tongue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @BenBolker, you could consider the `type` parameter for the `quantile()` function.  You are using a continuous distribution  so types 4 through 9 are relevant. For example:

```
 b[b <  quantile(b, probs = c(.05), type = 9)]
```

Types 4 and 6 will give what you were probably expecting

```
 [1] -1.893092 -3.263889
```

while 5, 7, 8, and 9 will give

```
 [1] -1.893092 -1.538927 -3.263889
```

The help file gives much detail about why, but in the end it comes down to the fact that there is no agreed upon method to estimate sample quantiles (including the median).

Comment: thank you @Elin. So say there are 59 student test scores, or 59 annual snow fall totals, depending on the method, there's some gray area as to whether two or three measurements are within the, say, highest 5th percentile? I wonder, any sense if certain disciplines, like say sociology or hydrology, tend to stick to one vs another? I saw some types were default in certain software.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't say it is gray, either there are 2 or 3.  The method is about how the value is calculated. The calculated values are different. As a result different specific observations fall below it.  I would say that your observation about the software is right -- in a given discipline I'd probably use the method that corresponds to one of the popular software packages or otherwise explain why I chose a particular method. You should be conscious of why you are using a particular method and if you read the references at the bottom of the help file they may help you think about that.

Comment: thank you. absolute coincidence that hydrology is mentioned there! In there I see `The default method is type 7, as used by S and by R < 2.0.0.` but under Author, there's a reference to `the version used in R >= 2.0.0`,  without a # given (I think the latest R version is ~3.4).  Do you read it as the default still being type 7, or am I missing something? I'm wondering if it's the same type 7, just computed maybe more efficiently.

Comment: I think, but don't know, that the types were introduced in version 2.0.0. R is an open source version of S so since S uses type 7, R by default uses type 7 and probably matches the previous default which would have matched S.  Also the R core team cares a lot about backward compatibility so it would have wanted existing code to yields the same result as it had before types were introduced.